# add exponential function given mean and intercept to cdf plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, exponential-distribution

Considering the following random data:

```
set.seed(123456)
# generate random normal data
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 5)
weights <- 1:100
df1 <- data.frame(x, weights)

#
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf()
```

We can create a general cumulative distribution plot.

But, I want to compare my curve to that from data used 20 years ago. From the paper, I only know that the data is *"best modeled by a shifted exponential distribution with an x intercept of 1.1 and a mean of 18"*

How can I add such a function to my plot?

```
+ stat_function(fun=dexp, geom = "line", size=2, col="red", args = (mean=18.1))
```

but I am not sure how to deal with the shift (x intercept)

Comment: `dexp` is a density function. `pexp` is a CDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think scenarios like this are best handled by making your `function` first outside of the `ggplot` call.

`dexp` doesn't take a parameter `mean` but uses `rate` instead which is the same as `lambda`. That means you want `rate = 1/18.1` based on properties of exponential distributions. Also, I don't think `dexp` makes much sense here since it shows the density and I think you really want the probability with is `pexp`.

your code could look something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
test <- function(x) {pexp(x, rate = 1/18.1)}
ggplot(df1, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf() +
    stat_function(fun=test, size=2, col="red")
```

[image]

you could shift your `pexp` distributions doing this:

```
test <- function(x) {pexp(x-10, rate = 1/18.1)}
ggplot(df1, aes(x)) + stat_ecdf() +
    stat_function(fun=test, size=2, col="red") +
    xlim(10,45)
```

[image]

just for fun this is what using `dexp` produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understand concept of mean for exponential function. However, generally, when you pass function as an argument, which is `fun=dexp` in your case, you can pass your own, modified functions in form of: `fun = function(x) dexp(x)+1.1`, for example.
Maybe experimenting with this feature will get you to the solution.